# Multiple IP addresses vs. Reverse Proxy / Apache Rewriting

Tags: firewall, performance, router, load-balancing, stability

We're a small business and trying to decide on the best architecture for our internal boxes. We have some dev, production and staging environments. All of them are publicly accessible (but of course restricted by password).

For a rather simple need, I really don't see the need to have multiple ip addresses for each box. Seems to add un-necessary complexity. Instead I'm debating that it's better at this stage to just have a single public IP address with a Reverse Proxy (e.g. Squid) or just use rewriting in Apache to forward the requests to appropriate servers (depending on the domain name).

What are your thoughts? Have I got this wrong and Multiple IP Addresses are the way to go regardless of the size of the organisation? What approach have you typically chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd favour varnish or ha-proxy over squid for reverse proxying. However having seperate IP addresses gives a lot more flexibility - e.g. if you want to access boxes remotely using different protocols such as ssh. Proxying also entails one more tier, affecting perfromance and complicating diagnostics.

Comment: That's a good point. I had only originally thought about port 80 (since most of them are HTTP servers) but they will also need SSH access. This is definitely easier with IP separation.

Comment: (it also makes it simpler to check that all the nodes are up if you add unique names for each IP address)

Answer (score 2):

We use apache for rewriting/proxing to internal web servers, and it works pretty well. However, be careful how you setup your virtual hosts on the server, as the first rule that matches the pattern is the one that is chosen.  The order can matter.. For example, if you have a default or fallback place to forward to (such as your main site) it needs to be last.

Also, SSL gets a bit trickier.  You would need wildcard cert for *.yourdomain.com and then use URL matching for each virtual host to forward.  The wildcard certs can be a bit trickier, but not too bad.

Comment: That's a good point. I had only originally thought about port 80 (since most of them are HTTP servers) but they will also need SSH access. This is definitely easier with IP separation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any inherit badness with using Apache to proxy back to the appropriate internal servers.  Just setup windcard DNS so you can have dev.foo.com, test.foo.com, etc, then setup vhost definitions with the corresponding proxy rules to route back to the appropriate boxes.  That said, you can use a few tools to do this; Apache's not the only solution.

As for certs, unless you absolutely need valid dev/test certs, just make your own wildcard cert.

Also, Squid's a good FORWARD proxy, but it's pretty heavy/crap the other way around.